# Copy cells in a row to another sheet considering a unique reference number

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I an trying to extract data from sheet "Record" by matching an entered reference number in sheet "Form" with those numbers in column B of "Record." I was able to come up with the VB code below through command button click.  However, it will only return a single value from sheet "Record" column i and coding for each will really be time consuming.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
With Application.WorksheetFunction
   Sheets("Form").Range("b:b") = _
   .Index(Sheets("Record").Range("h:h"), .Match(Sheets("Form").Range("i13"), Sheets("Record").Range("b:b"), 0), 1)

End With
End Sub
```

I'm wondering if is it possible to copy values from sheet "Record" columns H-Q to sheet "Form" columns B-K if the reference number in cell I13 of sheet "Form" matches any value on column B of sheet "Record?" Because what i encounter most of the time is returning the entire row.
I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Do you need it to be a VBA solution? Can be done easily using formulas.

Comment: Yes. I actually need it in vb. Thanks

Comment: Hi. One row, however, only need part of the row. Example only values on cell b:g

Answer (score 0):

It might be brute force, but I think the best way is to loop through the data like this:

```
'Find the last row of data
Public Function Get_Last_Row_Find(ByVal rngToCheck As Range) As Long
    Dim rngLast As Range
    Set rngLast = rngToCheck.Find(what:="*", searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If rngLast Is Nothing Then
        Get_Last_Row_Find = rngToCheck.Row
    Else
        Get_Last_Row_Find = rngLast.Row
    End If
    If Get_Last_Row_Find <= 1 Then
        Get_Last_Row_Find = 2
    End If
End Function

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click

x = Get_Last_Row_Find(Sheets("Record").Range("B:B")
for i = 1 to x
    if Sheets("Form").Range("I13").Value = Sheets("Record").Range("B:B").Offset(i-1,0).Value then 'match
        Worksheets("Record").Range("H"&i&":Q"&i).Copy _ 
destination:=Worksheets("Form").Range("B"&i&":K"&i)
next i
```

Note the two methods of "offsetting": you can use the .Offset method or you can use a variable and concatenate it within the Range("") text.

Code not tested.